# Why I get different results in my pc and vps with cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, curl

I want to get user info using cURL in PHP from *imooc.com*. So I write a small program for resolving it.My method is visit `www.imooc.com/space/profile/uid/{$uid}` ( `{$uid}` is auto-increment) and save data to my database. But sometime I will meet `302 redirect`. I found that `imooc.com` have two redirect sites, for example, when you visit `www.imooc.com/space/profile/uid/110073` or `www.imooc.com/space/profile/uid/212328`, you will find they redirect to different sites(`www.imooc.com/error/noexists` or `www.imooc.com/course/list`).

In my pc and vps, I can get the same result when redirect to `www.imooc.com/error/noexists`, but if redirect another site, my pc could perfect solve it, while my vps only do nothing, it doesn't work.

How can I reslove this problem?
This is my codes:

```
// connect to DB
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tools";
$link = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8';"));

$sql = "SELECT MAX(uid) FROM imooc";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$lastUid = $stmt->fetch()[0];

$uid = $lastUid+1;

// I execute this script using cron every minute, so I use loop to make sure it will get 40 sites
while(($lastUid + 40) >= $uid){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.imooc.com/space/profile/uid/{$uid}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $str = strstr($output, "的个人详情-慕课网</title>", true);
    if ($str === false) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO imooc(uid,username, site, learntime, experience, usersex, usercity) VALUES(:uid, :username, :site, :learntime, :experience, :usersex, :usercity)";
        $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', '没有找到此人');
        $stmt->bindValue(':site', '没有该人的职业信息');
        $stmt->bindValue(':learntime', '没有找到该人的学习时间');
        $stmt->bindValue(':experience', '没有找到该人的学习经验');
        $stmt->bindValue(':usersex', '没有找到该人的性别');
        $stmt->bindValue(':usercity', '没有找到该人的城市');
        $stmt->execute();
        $uid++;
        continue;
    }

    // get user-name
    $title = strstr($str, "<title>");
    $name = substr($title, 7);

    // get user-site
    $str = strstr($output, '<span class="user-site">');
    $span = strstr($str, "</span>", true);
    $site = trim(substr($span, 24));

    // get learn-time
    $str = strstr($output, '<p class="mp-num">');
    $span = strstr($str, '</p>', true);
    $learntime = trim(substr($span, 18));

    // get user-experience
    $str = strstr($output, '<span class="mp-num">');
    $span = strstr($str, '</span>', true);
    $experience = trim(substr($span, 21));

    // get user-sex
    $str = strstr($output, '<em >');
    $span = strstr($str, '</em>', true);
    $usersex = trim(substr($span, 5));
    if ($str === false) {
        $usersex = '保密';
    }

    // get user-city
    $str = strstr($output, '<span>所在城市：</span>');
    $span = strstr($str, '</ul>', true);
    $city = strip_tags(substr($span, strlen('<span>所在城市：</span>') ) );
    $usercity = str_replace(' ', '', $city);

    // insert data into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO imooc(uid,username, site, learntime, experience, usersex, usercity) VALUES(:uid, :username, :site, :learntime, :experience, :usersex, :usercity)";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':site', $site);
    $stmt->bindParam(':learntime', $learntime);
    $stmt->bindParam(':experience', $experience);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usersex', $usersex);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usercity', $usercity);
    $stmt->execute();
    $uid++;
}
```

I use XAMPP V3.2.1 with 5.6.11 version of PHP, and my vps PHP version is 5.6.11, too.

Comment: "other site" and "doesn't work" don't help us see where the problem is. "doesn't work" is probably the worst possible choice of explanation *how* something doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get content from valid page (non-redirect, existing uid) you should just check if redirect occurred and skip such pages.

To do this check curl response meta info (response headers) for response code (http_code) or redirect_url.